# Why the plethora of return types from Web API Controller Actions?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Can someone provide an explanation for the uses, benefits, and cons of the various action return types possible from Web API controllers?

What I mean is, what is the difference between each of these?

```
public T Get(int id) { ... }
public IActionResult Get(int id) { ... }
public Task<IActionResult> Get(int id) { ... }
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id) { ... }
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) { ... }
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id) { ... }
```

I see a smattering of all of the above in use and wonder why and what are recommended best practices?

Comment: Check documentation here [Action Results in Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results)

Comment: You are also mixing asp.net core and asp.net web api 2

Comment: You are missing `public ActionResult`, `public JsonResult`, `public FileResult`, `public PartialViewResult`, etc. :)

Comment: LOL! Oh, I knew there were more options, Andrew but I didn't want to confuse myself more than I already was. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the link, Nkosi. I understand the difference between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core but not what you mean by "mixing asp.net core and asp.net web api 2".

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.ihttpactionresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**public T Get(int id) { ... }** -> Your returned object will be serialised to json/xml and returns as Http content. No control over the rest of the HTTP Response

**public IActionResult Get(int id) { ... }** -> Mostly used in ASP.NET MVC. Allows different types of ActionResults (i.e ViewResult, FileResult, JsonResult etc.) to be returned, some of which is used to return the correct View in MVC.

**public Task Get(int id) { ... }** -> As above but wraps the result in a task. Tasks are used to allow asynchronous programming to free up the threads while not in use. However, in this case without the async modifier it is just overhead.

**public async Task Get(int id) { ... }** -> Allows the await keyword to be used within the method body to execute suitable methods asynchronously

**public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) { ... }** -> Asynchronous by default. Specifies a command that creates HttpResponseMessage object. You can take advantage of helper methods (i.e Ok(), NotFound(), Redirect() etc) to create your response and you have full control of the returned HTTP Response (content, headers etc.) Oh and it makes Unit Testing easier!

**public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id) { ... }** -> As above but you have to create the HttpResponseMessage yourself. Full control of the Http Response again.

For WebApi, I would say that best practice is **IHttpActionResult**. Unless you are building something very simple, in which case you can simply return T.

You can find more details in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Great answer that helps me a lot. Thank you very much gp!